# Seaborn tsplot windowed estimators

Tags: plot, time-series, seaborn

I want to do a tsplot where the estimator is a windowed function like a rolling mean rather than a mean. Ideally I'd like to pass a rolling mean function as the `estimator` parameter of `tsplot()`, but individual timepoints are passed into that estimator. So, it looks like I'm stuck with pre-processing my data.

Is that correct? Is there a good approach that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Are you hoping to get a confidence interval? What structure does your data have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to do, but the bootstrap function used in `tsplot` to compute the confidence interval gets the whole array and `axis=0`, and then resamples rows of the array before reducing over operations. So this seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(25, 40), axis=1)
sns.tsplot(data=data)
```

[image]

```
def rolling_mean(data, axis=0):
    return pd.rolling_mean(data, 4, axis=1).mean(axis=axis)

sns.tsplot(data=data, estimator=rolling_mean)
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! I'm not sure why I thought rolling_mean didn't get the whole array.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I'm not really sure there's any reason to do the rolling mean across time in each iteration of the bootstrap. You should get the same result by calling it once first and passing the result into `tsplot`. Things might be different if you reverse the order of operations; I'm not sure what is the right way to do it.

Comment: As long as these are all linear operations, I would guess the order doesn't affect the result. But I guess treating the data beforehand could be more efficient.